# what is the meaning of Four gradation grayscale-color?

Tags: graphics, fonts, colors

I am implementing a standard that gives four colors in RGB format.
1). Foreground-color
2). Color-1
3). background-color
4). Color-2

and it standard says that I need to create one single grayscale-color with these four colors, I am not able to get what does this mean? I mean how to mix them. has anybody worked on some similar concept?

Usage for this mixed grayscale color is only for text drawing. To me it looks like it is something to do with anti-aliazing, It looks like left side anti-aliazing should be color-1 center is color-2, right side anti-aliazing is of color-2.

Comment: What standard is that? Perhaps if we get to read it firsthand, we can actually make sense of what you are asking.

Comment: It is here http://www.dmbtest.com/shop/download.php?dnfile=ARIB-STD-B24_V5_0_VOL_2(2_2).pdf&PHPSESSID=7bf3b09178bc526c769903224e9f11d8, name of this property is grascale-color-index.

Comment: Nobody is going to read you 200 page PDF just to answer you question.

Comment: @Ross, Conquevas read it. :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look to the specs, they are not RGB colors, but indexed colors. For each of the colors you can use a value from 0 to 255 (8 seems to a "background" color alias).

If you do something like:

```
div, p, span, a, input { background-color-index: 8; }
p, input { grayscale-color-index: 30 15; }
```

Then `p` and `input` tags will show a gradiation like `Foreground -> 30 -> 15-> 8` but I have no clue on the foreground color index definition.

**EDIT:** This is my gest of what kind of gradiation is, but I'm not sure at all.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to your answer, foreground color index is you can say color in rgb format, so no worry for it, can you please give me a small example of gradation? That's the only thing I am not able to get  in this document. Again thanks for reading that document.